# My WSL terminal lost color

Tags: ubuntu, colors, terminal, windows-subsystem-for-linux

For some reason when I start the Ubuntu terminal in Windows, it doesn't show colors until I type bash. What could be the reason and how do I fix it?
When I installed WSL it always showed colors.

[image]

Answer (score 147):

The reason could be a modified `.bash_profile` file.
Try putting these lines to `~/.bash_profile`

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Or a better way is to run the below command from your terminal

```
echo "source ~/.bashrc" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

To know more about how do we set environment-variables and what role do files like `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile` play, you may want to read:

- [.profile or .bash_profile](https://superuser.com/questions/171035/profile-or-bash-profile)
- [How to create ~/.bash_profile and ~/.profile](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/99835/how-to-create-bash-profile-and-profile)
- [I cannot find .bash_profile in ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/510709/i-cannot-find-bash-profile-in-ubuntu)

Comment: This helped me a lot. I forgot I recently made a `~/.bash_profile` file and this essentially took the place of the default `~/.bashrc` bash profile where the color is set.

Comment: This is definitely the best and accepted answer. Great resources! Thank you.

Answer (score 21):

In your `.bashrc`, try uncommenting the following line in order to force color:

`#force_color_prompt=yes`

Comment: this is the easy answer!

Comment: This is definitely the easiest and best answer. Thank you! Was driving myself insane here.

Answer (score 16):

I ran into this forum hoping to find the solution to my problem. I eventually figured it out so here's how I fixed it:

1. Open up your terminal window by pressing `Ctl` + `r`, typing `bash` and pressing enter.
2. Make sure you're in your home directory by executing `cd ~`
3. Open up the bashrc file by executing `nano .bashrc`
4. Delete everything in that file and replace it with this:

   ```
   # ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
   # see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
   # for examples

   # If not running interactively, don't do anything
   case $- in
       *i*) ;;
       *) return;;
   esac

   # don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
   # See bash(1) for more options
   HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

   # append to the history file, don't overwrite it
   shopt -s histappend

   # for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
   HISTSIZE=1000
   HISTFILESIZE=2000

   # check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
   # update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
   shopt -s checkwinsize

   # If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
   # match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
   #shopt -s globstar

   # make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
   [ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

   # set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
   if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
       debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
   fi

   # set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
   case "$TERM" in
       xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;;
   esac

   # uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
   # off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
   # should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
   #force_color_prompt=yes

   if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
       if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
       # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
       # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
       # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
       color_prompt=yes
       else
       color_prompt=
       fi
   fi

   if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
       PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
   else
       PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
   fi
   unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

   # If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
   case "$TERM" in
   xterm*|rxvt*)
       PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
       ;;
   *)
       ;;
   esac

   # enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
   if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
       test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
       alias ls='ls --color=auto'
       #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
       #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

       alias grep='grep --color=auto'
       alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
       alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
   fi

   # colored GCC warnings and errors
   #export GCC_COLORS='error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:locus=01:quote=01'

   # some more ls aliases
   alias ll='ls -alF'
   alias la='ls -A'
   alias l='ls -CF'

   # Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
   #   sleep 10; alert
   alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

   # Alias definitions.
   # You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
   # ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
   # See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

   if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
       . ~/.bash_aliases
   fi

   # enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
   # this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
   # sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
   if ! shopt -oq posix; then
   if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
       . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
   elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
       . /etc/bash_completion
   fi
   fi
   ```
5. Save the file with `Ctl` + `o`
6. Reload the terminal. Try executing `. .bashrc` if it doesn't work. (notice the space between the two periods in that last command).

I don't know if the original poster will get this, but hopefully it will help a poor soul who stumbles upon it.

Comment: For some reason my .bashrc was empty. This fixed things for me.

Comment: But this will undo my alias that I added to bashrc?

Answer (score 0):

Another simple way of changing colors are by right clicking on the console bar and select properties.

I managed to change some colors but there is one I cannot modify as I don't know what it actually refers to. I am speaking about the blue color for the "current directory"..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might be running a different shell than bash. Some of them look the same. My current install WSL Ubuntu started with sh for one reason or another. This is how I fixed it.

Can check by doing

```
echo $SHELL
```

[image: SH Shell default]

If its anything other than /bin/bash you can change it by taking your username from before the @ if your shell is showing your username in prompt, in my case here cjohnson and issuing the command: sudo usermod -s /bin/bash cjohnson

If your current shell doesn't list your username in the prompt you can use the command: whoami

[image: sh to bash]

-s flash tells usermod to modify the shell for the user listed at end.

Then when you open a new shell should get the normal bash shell.

[image: bash shell]

Since no answer was picked. Figured this was as good of place as any to leave it as it was my first search result for this issue. A WSL terminal color wasn't showing up in.