# Issues with ASDF, Color, and Ruby Version in WSL2 Ubuntu Terminal, But No Problems in VSCode Terminal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, asdf

1. There is a difference in Ruby versions between WSL2 Ubuntu and when executed in VSCode.
   [ubuntu terminal: ruby -v result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRTB4.png)
   [vscode: ruby -v result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4infi.png)

In 'type -a ruby', asdf is reflected in VSCode but not in Ubuntu.
[ubuntu terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z86HP.png)
[vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aK4xy.png)

2. Also, asdf is installed, but it only works in VSCode. When 'asdf' is entered in the terminal Ubuntu, it does not work.
3. Ubuntu text color issue
   Normally it should appear like this:
   [color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54xgk.png)

But when restarting Ubuntu, it turns black and white:
[ubuntu terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYAhh.png)

However, there is a solution to this. By following the steps up to the second point in this document GoRails Setup for Ubuntu 22.04, the color issue in Ubuntu and the 'ruby -v' issue are resolved.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git-core zlib1g-dev build-essential libssl-dev libreadline-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev software-properties-common libffi-dev
```

```
cd
git clone https://github.com/excid3/asdf.git ~/.asdf
echo '. "$HOME/.asdf/asdf.sh"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo '. "$HOME/.asdf/completions/asdf.bash"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'legacy_version_file = yes' >> ~/.asdfrc
echo 'export EDITOR="code --wait"' >> ~/.bashrc
exec $SHELL
```

However, after restarting, the settings reset, and I have to repeat the process mentioned above. What could be the problem?

The .bash_profile file does not contain any content.

Comment: I solved problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48761771/my-wsl-terminal-lost-color thanks!